# API return the lessons of a course and I need to save all of them with its course

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, query-builder

I have two endpoints:

/api/courses

/api/courses/{course_id}/lessons

The API is built from an external server so it is not possible to change the endpoints and response.

The first endpoint returns a json response with all the courses:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Course1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Course2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Course3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Course4"
  }
]
```

The second one returns all the lessons without the course_id so only we have the course_id on the url.

```
[
  {
    "start": "2020-02-01T14:00:00+00:00",
    "end": "2020-02-01T14:10:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-02-01T14:10:00+00:00",
    "end": "2020-02-01T14:50:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-02-01T14:50:00+00:00",
    "end": "2020-02-01T15:10:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-02-01T15:10:00+00:00",
    "end": "2020-02-01T15:30:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-02-01T15:30:00+00:00",
    "end": "2020-02-01T16:10:00+00:00"
  }
]
```

So my question is if it is possible to find a solution to get all the lessons and save it with the course_id without having to call the endpoint for each course we have.
Let's have a look my example:

```
    
    $ur_base = "http://localhost:8080/api/";
    $courses = DB::table('courses')->get(); // Here we get all the courses saved in our database because we already saved them from the first endpoint.
```

The problem is in the second endpoint because to save all the lessons with their course, I need to call the endpoint /api/courses/{course_id}/lessons as many times as courses we have.

```
    $courses = DB::table('courses')->get();

    foreach ($courses as $course) {
        $lessonsResponse = Http::get($url_base . 'courses/' . $course->id . '/lessons');

        if($lessonsResponse->status() !== 500) {
            $lessons = $lessonsResponse->json();

            foreach ($lessons as $lesson) {
                DB::table('lessons')
                    ->insert([
                        'start' => Carbon::make($lesson['start']),
                        'end' => Carbon::make($lesson['end']),
                        'course_id' => $course->id,
                    ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is that a good way to save all the lessons? What about performance? I was thinking to use Graphql.

Do you think it can solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a requirement to have two separate endpoints? Can't you combine both in a single endpoint and have a boolean parameter (getLessons) which when set to true, the API will return each course's lessons along with course details?

Comment: It's not possible the endpoint is an API from another server